# Akka Remote Actors- : can not able to establish a connection between local and remote actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

Hi I am following this [tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-akka-actors-remote-example) and I copy pasted the code as it is except I changed the port from 5150 to 2552 and I am facing thease errors 
HelloLocal project errors

```
 [warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Running HelloLocal 
[INFO] [11/04/2014 22:37:50.707] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [11/04/2014 22:37:51.857] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.1.1:2552]
[INFO] [11/04/2014 22:37:51.863] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.1.1:2552]
[ERROR] [11/04/2014 22:37:51.904] [LocalSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [RemoteActorRefProvider] Error while looking up address [akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552]
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: No transport is loaded for protocol: [akka], available protocols: [akka.tcp]
    at akka.remote.Remoting$.localAddressForRemote(Remoting.scala:88)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.localAddressForRemote(Remoting.scala:130)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.actorFor(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:321)
    at akka.actor.ActorRefFactory$class.actorFor(ActorRefProvider.scala:258)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.actorFor(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at LocalActor.<init>(HelloLocal.scala:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:45)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:361)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

[INFO] [11/04/2014 22:37:51.913] [LocalSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/RemoteActor] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://LocalSystem/user/LocalActor#543076206] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/RemoteActor] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

HelloRemote project errors are:

```
[info] Running HelloRemote 
Remote Actor receive messgage : The remote actor is alive  
[INFO] [11/04/2014 22:38:40.915] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#-1308265074] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am new in akka and for learning purpose I am following this tutorial and now there are errors please help me to solve them

edit after following the akka-remitng 2.3.6 now i am having different errors
aplication.conf (helloLocal)

```
akka {
actor {
provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
}
remote {
enabled-transport =  ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
netty.tcp {
hostname = "127.0.0.1"
port = 0
}
}
}
```

HelloLoca.scala
import akka.actor._

```
class LocalActor extends Actor {
  //create the remote actor 
  val remote = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/RemoteActor")

  var counter = 0
def receive = {
    case "START" =>
        remote ! "Hello from the LocalActor"
    case msg: String =>
        println(s"LocalActor received message: '$msg'")
        if (counter < 5) {
            sender ! "Hello back to you"
            counter += 1
        }
  }
}
object HelloLocal extends App{
  implicit val system =ActorSystem("LocalSystem")
  val localActor =system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor],name="LocalActor")
  localActor ! "START"

}
```

and HelloRemote application.conf is

```
    akka {
    actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
   remote {
    enabled-transport =  ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
     hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 2552
    }
    }
    }
```

These are the errors now 
HelloLocal

```
[info] Running HelloLocal 
[INFO] [11/05/2014 12:42:32.674] [run-main-1] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [11/05/2014 12:42:34.031] [run-main-1] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:45047]
[INFO] [11/05/2014 12:42:34.040] [run-main-1] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:45047]
[WARN] [11/05/2014 12:42:34.367] [LocalSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:45047/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FHelloRemoteSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2552-0/endpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:45047] -> [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552]: Error [Invalid address: akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] [
akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.Transport$InvalidAssociationException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2552
]
[WARN] [11/05/2014 12:42:34.419] [LocalSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13] [Remoting] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2552
[INFO] [11/05/2014 12:42:34.451] [LocalSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://LocalSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://LocalSystem/user/LocalActor#1798933307] to Actor[akka://LocalSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

HelloRemote errors are

```
[info] Running HelloRemote 
Remote Actor receive messgage : The remote actor is alive  
[INFO] [11/05/2014 12:42:35.654] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#1925624739] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using a more up to date version of akka than was used in the tutorial.

For 2.2.3 and above your configuration needs to resemble

```
akka {
 actor {
  provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
 }
remote {
  enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
  netty.tcp {
   hostname = "127.0.0.1"
   port = 2552
  }
 }
}
```

Depending on your version you can find more information at : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/remoting.html

Comment: I am assuming you started the remote actor first and then attempted to send your message?

Comment: i am starting the local actor first then remote actors because at the end of tutorial its mentioned "When the local actor system starts, it will send an initial message to the remote actor system. The remote actor will send a reply" so for this I started the local actor first then remote actor

Comment: You need to start the remote actor first. When you start the local first it sends a message to a nonexistent remote system.

Comment: thank you so much :) its working now can u please suggest me some reading material on akka remoting ..akka documentation is very abstract on remoteing